What are the waters above the expanse in Genesis 1:6-7?
On the second day of His creation God made the expanse (רָקִיַע raqiya‘) among the waters as a separation ( מַבְדִּ֔יל mavdiyl) between the waters below and the waters above.
6: ​vayyo’mer ’Elohim yᵉhiy raqiya‘ bᵉtokh hammayim
And God said let an expanse be within the waters
viyhiy mavdiyl beyn mayim lamayim
and let [it] be [active (the stem of the participle is hifil)] a separation between waters to [the (the article is from the vowel only)] waters.
7: vayya‘as ’Elohim ’et-haraqiya‘
And God made the expanse
vayyavdel beyn hammayim ’asher mittaḥat laraqiya‘
and caused a division (the verb is again in the hifil stem) between the waters that are under the expanse
uveyn hammayim ’asher me‘al laraqiya‘
and the waters that are above the expanse
vayᵉhiy-khen
and [it] was so.
8: ​vayyiqra’ ’Elohim laraqiya‘ shamayim
And God called the expanse "heavens" (...)
My question originates from the fact that on the fourth day God placed the sun, moon, and all the stars in the same expanse. The waters above cannot, therefore, be the clouds, as these waters have often been understood to refer to.
Furthermore, assuming that the clouds are being spoken of, the separation between the waters above and the waters below the expanse would be contradicted by the water cycle, which is, besides being apparent to natural observation, is also spoken of in Isaiah 55:10 as a metaphor for the sending of God's Word. The clouds are, therefore, to be considered as part of the waters below the expanse that are collected into the seas as it is written in Genesis 1:9-10.

Waters and seas are often symbolic in scripture. One interpretation is that the symbolism is prophetic of a people who shall be 'seated in the heavenlies', in the third heavens, above the visible firmament. This interpretation veiws the first chapter of Genesis as a view of Creation as such that is to say not the first creation but Creation as an absolute concept.

“Praise him, you highest heavens, and you waters above the heavens!”
‭‭Psalm‬ ‭148‬:‭4‬ ‭those waters are still there after Noah’s flood. They are not symbolic they are literal waters.

Why are you translating raqiya as "expanse"?

I like the idea that Genesis 1 sheds light also on the observable Universe telling us also why we don't find water in the space. Moreover it makes me particularly happy the idea of beingspiritually connected with the otherwise unreachable waters above the heavens Genesis 1:6-7 (and likely Ps 148:4 too) speak about makes me particularly happy.  I translated raqiya with expanse because in my opinion it gives the idea of "space" more than firmament does, but I acknowledge that firmament, unlike expanse, renders the qatil pattern of the Hebrew root resh+qof+ayin basically meaning "to stamp".

The waters above the raqiya' are just that, waters above the solid dome encompassing the earth. The cosmology here is shared across Ancient Southwest Asia, where there's a colossal ocean above the firmament which is what gives the sky it's blue color.
The "waters above" are very clearly used in Genesis 7:11 during the flood:

בִּשְׁנַת שֵׁשׁ־מֵאוֹת שָׁנָה לְחַיֵּי־נֹחַ בַּחֹדֶשׁ הַשֵּׁנִי בְּשִׁבְעָה־עָשָׂר יוֹם לַחֹדֶשׁ בַּיּוֹם הַזֶּה נִבְקְעוּ כׇּל־מַעְיְנֹת תְּהוֹם רַבָּה וַאֲרֻבֹּת הַשָּׁמַיִם נִפְתָּחוּ


In the six hundredth year of Noaĥ’s life, in the second month, the seventeenth day of the month, on that same day were all the fountains of the great deep broken open, and the windows of heaven were opened (Koren Bible)


Surely you know that הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם is always plural in Hebrew reflecting the ancient Hebrew view of the cosmos. Thus, the text here would literally read, "the windows of the heavens." The singular form of heaven comes from the Greek Septuagint. The "solid dome" over a flat earth concept has a medieval origin. That the earth was spherical was known for centuries before Christ and is found in manuscripts from the 5th century BCE. Thus, in addition to atmospheric water, ice from the solar system likely contributed to the flood as well as from the interior of the earth.

Our interpretations of scripture are often influenced by our worldview, including our beliefs about the formation of the earth.
The Hebrew word used here is always in the plural, heavens, which includes the clouds and birds of the air, the domain of the sun, moon, and stars, and the domain of God and the angels, which Paul refers to as “the third heaven” in 2 Corinthians 12:2.
Consider the following scientific research:
•   The earth was originally covered by water:
https://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2021/04/harvard-scientists-determine-early-earth-may-have-been-a-water-world/
•   The water below the surface of the earth is now believed to be as much as three times that in all the oceans combined:
https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn25723-massive-ocean-discovered-towards-earths-core/
•   Much of this water is older than the sun, indicating an extra-terrestrial source:
https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/earths-water-is-older-than-the-sun
Due to what we were taught in school, we don’t typically think of the majority of water being under the earth and coming from an extraterrestrial source. Thus, it would now make sense that our atmosphere does indeed separate the major two sources of water on the earth.
I think it’s best to always keep an open mind, both in science and in our understanding of the scriptures.
Hope this helps.

The simplest understanding of the Gen 1 record is to read it according to the common view of the agrarian society and mind-set of the farming community from which it sprang.  That is, an ancient farmer would observe very simple things:

water runs in rivers and accumulates in lakes and seas
the source of this water is above the place where "birds of the heavens" fly (V20).

Thus, we should recall several important principles:

Gen 1 is written, not from a modern scientific point of view but from what we would now call a simple agrarian point of view.  Such people had no idea of "planet earth" but understood simply that rain falls from the heavens on the land and water flows into creaks, rivers, lakes and seas.
the "heavens" (shamayim) denotes what we now call the atmosphere where birds fly (Gen 1:20, 26, 28, 30, 2:19, 20, 6:7, 7:23, 9:2, etc).
from a terrestrial observer's point of view, the sun and moon appear to occupy the same space as the birds, at least their light certainly does.  Indeed, Hebrew has perfectly good serviceable words for sun (שֶׁמֶשׁ  shemesh) and moon (יָרֵחַ yareach), but the writer of Gen 1 avoids them so as not to leave the impression that they actually exist in the atmosphere - only their light exists in our atmosphere.

Conclusion
"Waters above the heavens" refers to the clouds.
Ellicott reaches the same conclusion:

The waters which were under the firmament . . . the waters which were above the firmament.—While this is a popular description of
what we daily see—namely, masses of running water congregated upon
earth’s surface, and above a cloudland, into which the waters rise and
float—it is not contrary to, but in accordance with, science. The
atmosphere is the receptacle of the waters evaporated from the earth
and ocean, and by means of electrical action it keeps these aqueous
particles in a state of repulsion, and forms clouds, which the winds
carry in their bosom. So full of thoughtful contrivance and
arrangement are the laws by which rain is formed and the earth
watered, that they are constantly referred to in the Bible as the
chief natural proof of God’s wisdom and goodness. (See Acts 14:17.)

The Pulpit commentary is similar:

And divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament. The upper waters are not the
material of the stars (Delitzsch, Wordsworth), ... but the waters
floating about in the higher spaces of the air. The under waters are
not the lower atmospheric vapors, but the oceanic and terrestrial
waters.

